# Force error in erb when env var unset?

Tags: erb

If I use `<%= ENV['FOO'] %>` in an erb template without setting an environment variable named `FOO`, then it resolves to an empty string.

Is it possible to force an error (index error, anything) at this point instead; evaluating to a string iff `$FOO` exists?

Comment: you can try to make it safe: `ENV['FOO'].html_safe` that'll throw an error if `ENV['FOO']` is nil.

Comment: Hm, thank you, I'll do that for now - but I'd like something more semantically obvious if possible; I'm doing this outside of an HTML context.

Comment: So, if that var is required across your app, why don't you add a before_filter on application controller where you ask for it?

Comment: @mr_sudaca There is no app, when I said out of an HTML context, I should have been more clear: I'm using erb purely for template evaluation, no ruby anywhere else, it's just a convenient format and CLI tool for generic use.